# Can a Package containing several sub-packages be also called as a Library in Python?

Tags: python, package, libraries

I am a little bit confused in the difference between a package and a library. When I install packages from pypi.org, these packages contain several sub-packages, that contain modules. When I googled the difference between a package and I library, I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhPQP.png).

And that being the case, can a package contain several sub-packages be also called as a library? If no then what is a library? And what is the difference between a library and a package containing sub-packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Library

Most often will refer to the general library or another collection created with a similar format and use. The General Library is the sum of 'standard', popular and widely used Modules, witch can be thought of as single file tools, for now or short cuts making things possible or faster. The general library is an option most people enable when installing Python. Because it has this name "Python General Library" it is used often with similar structure, and ideas. Witch is simply to have a bunch of Modules, maybe even packages grouped together, usually in a list. The list is usually to download them. Generally it is just related files, with similar interests. That is the easiest way to describe it.

## Module

A Module refers to a file. The file has script 'in it' and the name of the file is the name of the module, Python files end with .py. All the file contains is code that ran together makes something happen, by using functions, strings ect. Main modules you probably see most often are popular because they are special modules that can get info from other files/modules. It is confusing because the name of the file and module are equal and just drop the .py. Really it's just code you can use as a shortcut written by somebody to make something easier or possible.

## Package

This is a termis used to generally sometimes, although context makes a difference. The most common use from my experience is multiple modules (or files) that are grouped together. Why they are grouped together can be for a few reasons, that is when context matters. These are ways I have noticed the term package(s) used. They are a group of Downloaded, created and/or stored modules. Which can all be true, or only 1, but really it is just a file that references other files, that need to be in the correct structure or format, and that entire sum is the package itself, installed or may have been included in the python general library. A package can contain modules(.py files) because they depend on each other and sometimes may not work correctly, or at all. There is always a common goal of every part (module/file) of a package, and the total sum of all of the parts is the package itself.

Most often in Python Packages are Modules, because the package name is the name of the module that is used to connect all the pieces. So you can input a package because it is a module, also allows it to call upon other modules, that are not packages because they only perform a certain function, or task don't involve other files. Packages have a goal, and each module works together to achieve that final goal.

Most confusion come from a simple file file name or prefix to a file, used as the module name then again the package name.

Remember Modules and Packages can be installed. Library is usually a generic term for listing, or formatting a group of modules and packages. Much like Pythons general library. A hierarchy would not work, APIs do not belong really, and if you did they could be anywhere and every ware involving Script, Module, and Packages, the worl library being such a general word, easily applied to many things, also makes API able to sit above or below that. Some Modules can be based off of other code, and that is the only time I think it would relate to a pure Python related discussion.